# configure google admob for expo

Tags: react-native, expo, admob

I am trying to integrate googles Admob service into my expo initialized react native app via the `expo-ads-admob` package. the package works successfully in the expo-go development environment, however when I build the app and via `eas build --profile development --platform ios` and install it onto my phone, it immediately closes as soon as I open it. I have already removed all imports of the Admob components within the app so it seems like just installing the package itself causes the app to crash at runtime. Since the app builds successfully, there are no error messages I can use to start debugging, any help would be greatly appreciated. This is the configuration in my app.json if that's relevant

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "MyApp",
    "slug": "MyApp",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#FFF"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "config": {
        "googleMobileAdsAppId": "ca-app-pub-TESTID"
      },
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.package.identifier"
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFF"
      },
      "config": {
        "googleMobileAdsAppId": "ca-app-pub-TESTID"
      },
      "package": "com.package.identifier"
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[expo-ads-admob](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/admob/) is deprecated, so when using EAS Build the app breaks.

Expo itself recommends using [react-native-google-mobile-ads](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-google-mobile-ads), or try uninstalling EAS with `npm uninstall -g eas-cli` and using `expo build`.